# cambiar formato de columna para rangos de horarios

Tags: pandas, date

tengo una base de datos con una columna de rangos de hora, es de tipo object. necesito pasar la columna a  formato time sin perder los rangos y poder trabajarla. ejemplo:

rango horario

0:00-23:59

20:00-23:59

12:00-15:59

8:00-11:59

este es mi codigo:

`data['Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Rango Hora'], errors='coerce')`

`data['Hora']`

La salida es la siguiente:

`0        2023-06-28 12:00:00-15:59`

`1        2023-06-28 20:00:00-23:59`

`2        2023-06-28 20:00:00-23:59`

`3        2023-06-28 12:00:00-15:59`

`4        2023-06-28 08:00:00-11:59`

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado hacer así como un ejemplo del resultado deseado.